# Sending a non-maskable interrupt to a virtual machine with VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I'm using a virtual machine to do kernel debugging on Mac OS X because it's cheaper and more convenient than another computer.

Unfortunately, contrary to the Windows equivalent, it's not possible to use the debugger to stop the kernel. To stop it, you have to send the machine a non-maskable interrupt. On a physical machine, you can do that with the correct debug flags at boot, and then holding both <kbd>⌘</kbd> keys while pressing the power button. However, this key combination can't quite be realized on a virtual machine.

I found a [sloppy script](http://cloudtone.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/vmware-fusion-can-you-diag-it-nmi/) that suspends the virtual machine, edits the suspended state to indicate that a NMI is pending, and resumes it, but this looks like a waste of time.

Is it possible to send a non-maskable interrupt to a virtual machine with VMware Fusion?

Comment: This is an old question but. 1) I doubt it. 2) What do you get when you press the NMI button on your host? That is assuming you have a physical button for that. Most servers do, but most consomer desktops left this out.

Comment: On my operating system you get a kernel crash dump so you can inspect and debug the state, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set/add the `0x4` bit flag to the `debug` argument of the `boot-args` variable through the `nvram` command. Here's an example:

`sudo nvram boot-args="debug=0x144 kext-dev-mode=1 kcsuffix=development pmuflags=1 -v"`

As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/build/build.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH221-BABDGEGF), among the other arguments, the `debug=0x4` flag lets you drop into debugger on NMI. This means that you can press `Command-Option-Control-Shift-Escape` on your VM and drop into debugger at any time (for some reason, you may also need to press `fn` if key combination mentioned above doesn't work).

Eventually, after setting breakpoints, inspecting memory, printing a backtrace etc., you'll need to type `continue` for the kernel to resume executing.

Comment: On a Mac host, will that initiate an NMI on the host or VM?

Comment: That will generate a NMI on your VM which gives an opportunity for the remote debugger to connect.

Then from the terminal of your host machine type `xcrun lldb`, then `(lldb) kdp-remote <vm ip>`

Comment: @zneak did that help you?

Comment: I haven't tried it. The question is from 3 years ago, I no longer use VMware or do kernel development.

Comment: Yes, this works. Just be sure the host doesn't have the same debug flag set, or you might NMI the host instead.